# JavaFX - getScene() returns null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx-8

I just started using JavaFX Scene Builder to build a small application.

It is made up of a controller class 'Login.java' which belongs to 'login.fxml', in which the FXML file 'registrierung.fxml' is loaded via a method called 'registrationClicked(ActionEvent event)':

```
public class Login {

@FXML
private void registrationClicked(ActionEvent event){
    try{
        ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/fxml/registrierung.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);      
        stage.setTitle("Registration");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I want to get a reference to the stage of 'registrierung.fxml' in the controller class 'Registrierung.java' via the root node vboxRoot:

```
@FXML
private VBox vboxRoot;

Stage stage = (Stage) vboxRoot.getScene().getWindow();
```

However 'getScene()' always leads to a NullPointerException. The controller classes for both FXML files are adjusted in Scene Builder.

This is how I set up the rood node in 'registrierung.fxml':

```
<VBox fx:id="vboxRoot" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="267.0" prefWidth="355.0" stylesheets="@../css/styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="businesslogik.Registrierung">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `vboxRoot` initialized?

Comment: I just quoted the way I set up the root node in the fxml file and in the controller class. Please take a look.

Comment: Where is that code? In an event handler?

Comment: At the moment it's a field in the 'Registrierung.java' controller class. I'm new to JavaFX, but for me it seems to be in the right position.

Comment: Since `vboxRoot` is injected by the `FXMLLoader`, it cannot possibly be initialized until after the controller is created. Hence it is `null` here. Moreover, the root of the FXML is not placed in a `Scene` (or, consequently, a `Stage`) until after the `FXMLLoader`'s `load` method is completed (just look at the order of your code in `registrationClicked(...)`). So you cannot possibly access the`Scene` or the `Stage` until after the load process (including the `initalize()` method) is complete. Access the window only when you need it, which is likely in an event handler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you are trying to get the scene for an object that has not been initialized yet. if you were doing the same operation in

```
@Override 
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) vboxRoot.getScene().getWindow();
}
```

or if you have an event that triggers once you click something (which executes after the scene has loaded)

```
@FXML
private void action(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Stage stage = (Stage) vboxRoot.getScene().getWindow();
}
```

This would work!

Answer (score 9):

I have run into this issue and have found by placing a call to a method like this (When the scene becomes visible and is attached to the node, this will fire):

```
 private void determinePrimaryStage() {
        rootPane.sceneProperty().addListener((observableScene, oldScene, newScene) -> {             
            if (oldScene == null && newScene != null) {
                // scene is set for the first time. Now its the time to listen stage changes.
                newScene.windowProperty().addListener((observableWindow, oldWindow, newWindow) -> {
                    if (oldWindow == null && newWindow != null) {
                        primaryStage = (Stage)newWindow;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }`
```

Then I can do something like this later:

```
if(primaryStage == null) {
    Platform.runLater(()-.{......
}else {
   //do whatever
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the Initializable interface did not work for me(Java 8).
The method getScene() always returned null for me. So i had to do the following:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyGui.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
//do stage and scene stuff - i skip it here
MyController controller = (MyController)loader.getController();
stage.setOnShown(controller::adjustUI);
```

And in the controller i have:

```
public void adjustUI(WindowEvent event) {
    Scene scene = myComponent.getScene();
    //do stuff and do ui adjustments here
}
```