# Clear Selection in table view on clicking on empty rows in javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a `TableView` with some rows. The user can select any row but when he clicks on empty rows or anywhere on the `Stage`, I want to clear his current selection of the `TableView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the last selected row, and check with a mouse listener on the scene if the click was on the selected row or somewhere else:

```
    ObjectProperty<TableRow<MyRowClass>> lastSelectedRow = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    myTableView.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
        TableRow<MyRowClass> row = new TableRow<MyRowClass>();

        row.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
            if (isNowSelected) {
                lastSelectedRow.set(row);
            } 
        });
        return row;
    });


    stage.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (lastSelectedRow.get() != null) {
                Bounds boundsOfSelectedRow = lastSelectedRow.get().localToScene(lastSelectedRow.get().getLayoutBounds());
                if (boundsOfSelectedRow.contains(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()) == false) {
                    myTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I am getting null pointer exception at line
 stage.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

Comment: If you have access to the `scene` object, just replace `stage.getScene()` in the code above with `scene`. Otherwise have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464238/javafx-getscene-returns-null

Comment: yes i had access to stage as well. It is now working fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

You can add a event filter to the `Scene` that uses the selection model of the `TableView` to clear the selection, if the click was on a empty row or anywhere outside of a `TableView`:

```
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, evt -> {
    Node source = evt.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();

    // move up through the node hierarchy until a TableRow or scene root is found 
    while (source != null && !(source instanceof TableRow)) {
        source = source.getParent();
    }


    // clear selection on click anywhere but on a filled row
    if (source == null || (source instanceof TableRow && ((TableRow) source).isEmpty())) {
        tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }
});
```